# Apache URL Rewrite like IIS How To?

Tags: apache-2.4

Sorry if this is answered better somewhere but I have not got to grips with the answers I have seen via search (probably down to my search terms more than anything else)

I am new to trying anything to do with web tech and previously found happiness in figuring out how to host multiple sites on one IIS server so the technical bar is low with me.

A colleague has created an internal site with a bunch of buttoned links to various web tools we have on site, this led to a page that displayed awfully and we found an answer that was only workable if I switched the site to an Apache server. I have cobbled through and got that up and running once I got the basic hang of Virtual hosts and a range of other things.

Now I am trying to move the other sites over and have run into a snag with some of the sites that had URL Re-Writes on IIS. Our helpdesk site for instance, is hosted on a separate server and is run from a different port, so DNS points helpdesk to the webserver and IIS had URL re write that sent requests to the correct location. Users only ever saw Helpdesk in the URL followed by which ever page they were visiting, /tickets, /portal and so on.

I have managed to create a virtual host for the helpdesk with a re-direct but the end user then has the full local name and port number for the URL rather than "helpdesk". Also, any links to http://helpdesk get re-directed but if I add a particular page like /tickets, the link doesn't work directly. Obviously I am not doing something right but my searches are driving me nuts.

What do I need to do in apache to get the same results as I was getting via IIS with sites hosted on other internal servers? A step by step for simpletons would be most appreciated.

This is what I had in web.config which was created by the URL Re-write rules in IIS: (I have removed the preceding < from each line so the data shows up in this post)

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

configuration>

    system.webServer>

        rewrite>

            rules>

                rule name="Proxy" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">

                    match url="*" />

                    action type="Rewrite" url="http://servername:9675/{R:1}" />

                /rule>

            /rules>

        /rewrite>

    /system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And this is what I have created in the http-vhosts.conf for the same site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName helpdesk
    ServerAlias helpdesk

    RedirectPermanent / http://servername:9675

(commented out)    ServerAdmin admin@fakedomain.com

    ErrorLog "logs/helpdesk-access.log"
    CustomLog "logs/helpdesk-access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. When you format stuff as "`code`" you won't have to omit any characters and can preserve formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our helpdesk site for instance, is hosted on a separate server and is run from a different port, so DNS points helpdesk to the webserver and IIS had URL re write that sent requests to the correct location. Users only ever saw Helpdesk in the URL followed by which ever page they were visiting, /tickets, /portal and so on.

That sounds like a rewrite rule that worked as a Reverse Proxy. In Apache you'd configure that with the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive, rather than the `Redirect` directive (which instructs a web browser that a resource has moved to a different URL and which instructs the browser to change the URL in the address bar and send a new request to the target location)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName helpdesk
    ProxyPass / http://servername:9675/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://servername:9675/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the above but got a Proxy error until I added a "/" after the port numbers and now it works an absolute treat!
Thank you so much, so frustrating not knowing an answer but super happy that this now works as it should.
Thanks again

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Updated my answer accordingly.